# Checking understanding about a derivation of bias and variance in the context of generalization in course notes

Tags: mathematical-statistics, bias-variance-tradeoff

[image]

Sorry for the long image. This derivation of bias and variance was given in publicly available course notes ([here](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ergrosse/courses/csc311_f21/readings/Generalization.pdf)) on pages 3 and 4.

I understand the first derivation. They showed that y* was the best possible prediction that the model can make since the expected MSE loss given the input $x$ is the smallest it can possibly be with this prediction of $y_*$ since the Bayes error is not dependent on y itself so it is effectively a constant. Please correct me if I misunderstand.

I don't understand the first step of the second derivation and I'm not too sure what they mean by "suppress the dependence on $x$ for simplicity". I tried recreating their steps on my own:

$E((y-t)^2) = \sum_x p(x)\cdot E((y-t)^2| \mathbf{x})$

$= \sum_x p(x)\cdot ((y-y_*)^2 + Var[t|\mathbf{x}]) = \sum_x p(x)\cdot (y-y_*)^2 + \sum_x p(x) \cdot Var[t|\mathbf{x}])$
$= E((y-y_*)^2) + \sum_x p(x) \cdot Var[t| \mathbf{x}]$

Not sure how to proceed from here, I don't know how they just subbed in $Var(t)$, since the law of total variance can't be used here unless I have a $Var(E[t|\mathbf{x}])$ term somewhere.

Comment: See [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter9/9_1_5_mean_squared_error_MSE.php) for a hint.

Comment: I took a look but I don't see the hint there, could you point me towards where I should look? Also is this with regards to the first derivation or the second one?